# splash screen iphone

Tags: iphone, screen, splash-screen

I am using Xcode 3.2.5 and simulator-4.2 and i am developing universal application in portrait and landscape mode for that i have set launch image in plist as UILaunchImageFile~iphone and UILaunchImageFile~ipad but my question is my splash screen is not rotated as well as i am not using xcode 4 so  i can set images in plist like
Default-Portrait.png * (768w x 1004h) and Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png (768w x 1004h)
Default-Landscape.png ** (1024w x 748h)

so can anyone have idea that how can change my splash screen orienattation and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your Info.plist:

```
UILaunchImageFile=Default.png
UILaunchImageFile~iPad=Default.png
```

Then, name your images,

For iPad:
"Default-Landscape~ipad.png",
"Default-Portrait~ipad.png",
"Default-PortraitUpsideDown~ipad.png"

For iPhone/iPod Touch
"Default-Landscape.png",
"Default-Portrait.png",
"Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png"

Comment: i found the solution by someone answer
that in first view in you have to write
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }

In second view you have to write
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}